# Moving objects with angle and units in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Hi I am learning unity/c# and I am stuck at a point please help...

I want a object like cube or sphere in 2 D environment to move to a particular spot without the use of x-axis and y-axis...
I want o specify the angle and units it should move. Like Move 4 units in 45 degree angle.

Thankyou alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to specify how many is 1 unit in your environment and then you can use trigonometrics to calculate your point.

and make a function like

```
public Vector2 GetCoordinates(float units, float angle){
  //Your awesome trigonometics code here!
}
```

Note:  **A** is your **current position**,**B** is the **final position**, and **c** is **your units'** and the **angle cb** is **your angle**.

**b** is your movement on x coordinate, and **a** is your movement in the y coordinate

[image]

Happy coding!
(if you need further explanation i can do it but try to figure out first :D)

Comment: Thx alot sir........... I have got the basic concept of what I should be doing........Although I have not met 100% of my sol...... But I am pretty sure I am near to it........ Thx alot again..........

Comment: No problem, if it worked, mark the answer as correct :D